# How to send an Email Template via Apex mentioning subject in the Apex Code

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, email-template, apex-email-service

I am trying to send an email using email template via. I have done it successfully but I want to mention the subject in Apex code. When I mention the subject in Apex code, it successfully sends the email but without the body.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();    

String[] toAddresses = new String[] {myContacts[cntinc].email};                                    
mail.setTemplateId(templateIdClient);
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setccAddresses(CcAddress);
mail.setSubject('test subject'); 
mail.setTargetObjectId(myContacts[cntinc].Id);
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
mail.setUseSignature(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `setSubject` for a `SingleEmailMessage` it will override your template.

**So if you are providing a subject you need to provide a body as well.**

But if you want the template body to be retrieved as it is and set the subject manually, you can use this workaround.

Use the method `Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, whoId, whatId);` which will retrieve the email body as per the `templateId`, `whoId` and `whatId` provided. Refer [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm) for documentation.

Your code will now become:

```
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {myContacts[cntinc].email};                                    
    mail = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateIdClient, myContacts[cntinc].Id, null);
    mail.setSubject('test subject'); 
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Id);
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    mail.setUseSignature(false);
```

See if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Excellent that this works.
The documentation implies it won't:

```
setSubject(subject)
Optional. The email subject line.
If you are using an email template, the subject line of the template overrides this value.
```